# How to set a server side request timeout in CXF/Spring Servlets?

Tags: spring, cxf

I have a web service which is connecting to a database on a backend to provide information. Sometimes the Database can be slow, and I'll end up with a client who disconnects after 10 seconds, but my server continues to process the request and I end up with a broken pipe exception.

I'm wondering if there is a way, on the web service side, to set a request timeout, so that if I spend more the `x` seconds to reply to a request made to me, that the servlet will throw an error back to the client, and the servlet will try to kill the thread processing the request.

Is this possible using CXF/Spring to provide a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using *HTTPClientPolicy* and *setReceiveTimeout* method. [Here](http://lhein.blogspot.com/2008/09/apache-cxf-and-time-outs.html) you can find details information how to configure it on a server side.